# Verify channel and role through discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make it so that when someone types $verify in the #verify channel they receive the "Members" role and it deletes the $verify message. It should also be able to delete any other message sent that isn't $verify. This is my code that doesn't work:

```
async def on_message(message):
    delmessage = client.get_channel(976724314600644649)
    if message == "$verify":
        await message.message.delete(delete_after=5)
        user = message.message.author
        role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Members")
        await user.add_roles(role)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Verified", description=f"You have been verified in LXVI", color=0x0000FF)
        await user.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await delmessage.purge(limit=1)
```

This code which I've commented out-

```
#async def verify(ctx):
#    await ctx.message.delete()
#    user = ctx.message.author
#    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Members")
#    await user.add_roles(role)
#    embed = discord.Embed(title="Verified", description=f"You have been verified in LXVI",
color=0x0000FF)
#    await user.send(embed=embed)
```

-works to simply verify the user when they type $verify and it deletes the message and sends them a dm, but it doesn't account for any other messages sent in the channel.

Comment: Try only deleting the message after you have done everything else you needed to do.  Maybe deleting it makes certain things like the `author` field change their value.

Comment: You're deleting the message anyways so check if the message is `$verify` then outside the `if` statement, delete the message. Else I don't really understand your problem, what don't work ?

Comment: Also, do you know for sure that `message == "str"` does what you want?  I doubt `message` is actually a string.  You should see if your if condition is true.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, [`<message>.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content) is a `str` but `<message>` isn't (a message is of the class [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message).

Comment: Please [edit] your post to narrow your question to a *specific programming problem*. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Why `message.message.delete`? Is your goal to prevent the user from sending anything (by deleting it) until they run `verify`? (Also don't use purge 1, just delete the specific message by ID)

Answer (score 0):

This deletes every message in the channel with the id of `976724314600644649`. It adds the role `Members` before  deleting if the message content is `$verify`.

```
async def on_message(message):
  if message.channel.id == 976724314600644649:
    if message.content == "$verify":
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Members")
        await message.author.add_roles(role)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Verified", description=f"You have been verified in LXVI", color=0x0000FF)
        await message.author.send(embed=embed)
    await message.delete()
```